# Can TCP data overlap in the buffer

Tags: c++, qt, networking, tcp

If I keep sending data to a receiver is it possible for the data sent to overlap such that they accumulate in the buffer and so the next read to the buffer reads also the data of another sent data?

I'm using Qt and `readAll()` to receive data and parse it. This data has some structure in it so I can know if the data is already complete or if it is valid data at all but I'm worried that other data will overlap with others when I call `readAll()` and so would invalidate this suppose-to-be valid data.

If it can happen, how do I prevent/control it? Or is that something the OS/API worries about instead? I'm worried partly because of how the method is called. lol

Comment: 8 months, 18 questions, **0 votes**. Moving along.

Comment: If `readAll` corrupted its own buffer (what you are describing), it would be useless.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to have a corrupt buffer. The way I see it, it's just a continuous line of memory that fills up as data goes in.

Comment: TCP data is reconstructed in the same order as it is sent, so you will read all data bytes in the exact same order. This is guaranted by the protocol itself. From the top page of wikipedia: *TCP provides reliable, ordered delivery of a stream of bytes from a program on one computer to another program on another computer.* And of course there is no overlapping or TCP would be totally useless. What can happen is that you send 2 x 200 bytes and read 300 and 100 bytes at the receiver side, so you can't rely that you fetch data with the same granularity as it was sent.

Comment: A function called `readAll` sounds like it will block until the requested size is read or there is an error. If the requested size is larger than one message then you will probably get more than one message, but the extra bytes read may not be a complete message.

Comment: @hochl that is my point. if I send 2 200 bytes of data, which are individual, is it possible that when I decide to read data I would read over 200 bytes where the first 200b is from data1 and the other 100b is the first part of data2.

Comment: Yes, you need to add information about your data stream like sending the size of a packet in 4 bytes and then the data so you can reconstruct the whole structure reliably. I don't think there's another way for this ... :(

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream based connection, not a packet based connection, so you may not assume that what is sent in one time will also be received in one time.  You still need some kind of protocol to packetize your stream.

For sending strings, you could use the nul-character as separator or you could begin with a header which contains a magic and a length.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readAll  this function snarfs all the data and returns it as an array.  I don't see how the API raises concerns about overlapping data. The array is returned by value, and given that it represents the entire stream, so what would it even overlap with? Are you worried that the returned object actually has reference semantics (i.e. that it just holds pointers to storage that is re-used in other calls to the same function?)

If send and receive buffers overlap in any system, that's a bug, unless special care is taken that the use is completely serialized. (I.e. a buffer is somehow used only for sending and only for receiving, without any mixup.)

Comment: No I mean, if I have a sender that continuously sends data to a reciever, when the reciever reads the buffer is there a chance that the reciever will snag some of other sent data. Say the sent data are individual strings, would string1 be read with some of string2 by the reciever?

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is a delimiting/framing problem, not "overlapping". The function reads the whole stream until the end, so string1 and string2 will be in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a fixed length header followed by variable length packet with the header holding the information of length of packet.

This way you can avoid worrying about packet boundaries. Say for example instead of just sending the string send the length of the string followed by the string. In the receiver end always read the length and then based on the length read the string.